# CNTK and progressive growing of networks

Tags: python, cntk

What would be the best way to train a neural network with CNTK and with progressive growing? I'm referring to the method described in [Progressive Growing of GANs for Improved Quality, Stability, and Variation](http://research.nvidia.com/publication/2017-10_Progressive-Growing-of).

The network is first trained with smaller resolutions. After a while new convolutional layers are added to the network that operate at higher resolutions. The already trained parameters of the lower resolution part need to be there after adding the new layers.

Is there an easy way to add the layers and transfer the already learned parameters?